# Main Window crashes on close in Qt - ProxyModel header return statement

Tags: c++, qt, crash, tablemodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

Having a problem with main window crashing on close, but only if I open the window normal size (not filling the screen) and then maximize it and close the window. If I open it normal size and close it, no problem. This project includes a tableview, tableModel and a ProxyModel. While debugging, it seems to be crashing on this statement in the proxy model header function:

return sourceModel()->headerData(section, orientation, role);

I'm assuming I am missing something in my main constructor based on what I've researched, but I'm not seeing it.

```
Main Window: 
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QString>
#include "XMLFile.h"
#include "XMLReader.h"
#include "XMLWriter.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QAction>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include "TableModel.h"
#include "ProxyModel.h"
#include <QItemSelectionModel>
#include "CustomTableView.h"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT   
    QWidget *centralWidget;   


public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    const QString filename;

public slots:
    void ReceiveMessage( const QString &message );  

signals:
      void readXmlFile( const QString &fileName );
      void getXmlTableData();
      void setFilter( QString );

private slots:
    void on_actionOpen_triggered();
    void on_actionFind_triggered();
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_tableView_activated(const QModelIndex &index);
    void on_actionExport_XML_triggered();
    void on_actionExit_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString xmlFileName;
    QFile file;    
    XMLReader xmlReader;
    XMLWriter xmlWriter;
    QVector<QString> xmlArray;
    QString filter = "";
    CustomTableView *tableView;
    TableModel mTableModel; 
    ProxyModel* proxyModel;    
    QString accountValue;
    QString deptValue;
    QString yearValue;
    QString filterText;

    void createItems();
    void createConnections();


};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QApplication>
#include "XMLReader.h"
#include "XMLWriter.h"
#include "XMLFile.h"
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QModelIndexList>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , xmlReader( filename )  
    , xmlWriter( filename, &mTableModel )
    //, tableView( NULL )
    //, proxyModel( NULL )
    //, m_xmlView(NULL)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);   
    connect(&xmlReader, SIGNAL(SendMessage(const QString)), this, SLOT(ReceiveMessage(const QString)));

    /* Setup tableview */
    tableView = new CustomTableView(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tableView);
    tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);


    /* Table Model Setup */
    proxyModel = new ProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(&mTableModel);
    createConnections();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::ReceiveMessage(const QString &message)
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Warning", "Cannot open file : " + message);
}


void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
     QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName((this),"Open file");
     xmlReader.readFile(filename);
     setWindowTitle(filename);
     createItems();
}


void MainWindow::createItems()
{
    xmlArray = xmlReader.getXmlData();
    int tableSize = xmlArray.size();  
    QStringList strList;
    QString strSplit = "";
    QVector<TableItem> rows;

    /* Split into individual items, add as row to tableItem array.*/
    /* Insert each tableItem array into the table model. */
    for( int row = 0; row < tableSize; row++ )
    {
        TableItem newRow;
        strSplit = xmlArray[row];
        strList = strSplit.split("|");

        for( int k = 0; k < strList.length(); k++)
        {
          newRow.setData(k, strList[k] );
        }
        rows << newRow;
    }

    mTableModel.initModel( rows );
    QAbstractItemModel* model = nullptr;
    model = proxyModel;
    tableView->setModel( model );
    tableView->setColumnHidden(0, true); 

}

void MainWindow::createConnections()
{
    QObject::connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), proxyModel, SLOT(setAccount(QString)));
    QObject::connect(ui->lineEdit_2, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), proxyModel, SLOT(setDept(QString)));
    QObject::connect(ui->lineEdit_3, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), proxyModel, SLOT(setYear(QString)));
    QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(setFilter(QString)), proxyModel, SLOT(setSearchFilter(QString)));
}


void MainWindow::on_actionFind_triggered()
{
   /* Open find string dialog */
   bool ok;
   QString filterText =  QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Find"),
                                       tr("Search for string:"), QLineEdit::Normal,"", &ok);
   setFilter( filterText );
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    /* Clear filter values */
    ui->lineEdit->setText("");
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText("");
    ui->lineEdit_3->setText("");
    setFilter("");
}

void MainWindow::on_tableView_activated(const QModelIndex &index)
{
}

void MainWindow::on_actionExport_XML_triggered()
{
    /* Open save file dialog, call xmlWriter */
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save XML File"), ".", tr("XML files (*.xml)"));    
    xmlWriter.WriteFile(filename);  
}

void MainWindow::on_actionExit_triggered()
{
    QApplication::quit();
}
```

WORKING CODE:  MainWindow.cpp

```
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    , xmlReader( filename )
{

    ui->setupUi(this);   
    connect(&xmlReader, SIGNAL(SendMessage(const QString)), this, SLOT(ReceiveMessage(const QString)));

    /* Setup tableview */
    tableView = new CustomTableView(this);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tableView);
    tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);



    /* Table Model Setup */
    proxyModel = new ProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(&mTableModel);
    createConnections();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete proxyModel;   /* Newly added */
    delete tableView;    /* Newly added */
    delete ui;
}
```

I can upload more source code if needed. Thanks for any insight here.

-d

Comment: upload all source codes

Comment: You need to run your code under a debugger and examine the call stack at the point of the crash.

Comment: don't upload just *more* source code, upload a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I doubt many people are willing to read even more code. While minimizing your code, you might find the problem yourself. And with the minimized example, people will be able to help much better, eventually.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I've uploaded all pertinent cpp files. pasbi, I get it, and will try to put together enough to compile a working program later today if possible.

Comment: Just a bit more info, if I close the app using QApplication::closeAllWindows() it closes without error. If I use QApplication::quit(), I get the error. And again, this only happens if I open the program, resize the window and exit. If I don't resize, everything closes without error. Could this be caused by the order objects are being closed? I'm not initializing everything on the heap, in fact the tableModel is NOT on the heap, and I wonder if it's being deleted before the proxy model can perform that last function call.

Comment: ok, pasbi, you were correct...I think...    While creating a minimal version of the project, it occurred to me that my heap related objects were not getting deleted. I added delete statements for the 2 objects I created using "new" and it closes without crashing. (see code above in my original post) This does bring up another question however. Shouldn't these objects be deleted with ui?  Thanks again for the help.